# How to manage the scrollbehavior for each screen when using a common TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, I'm using a single TopAppBar that is shared across all screens through a Scaffold and applying the exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior.

If I move to another screen while the TopAppBar is scrolled away and disappears, it will remain disappeared.

I tried to use a separate TopAppBar for each screen, but this time, there is a problem that the scroll state is not maintained when I back to previous screen.

So, here's what I'm curious about:

1. Is there a way to use different scrollbehaviors for each screen when using a single shared TopAppBar?
2. How to maintain the scrollbehavior state for each screen when using a separate TopAppBar for each screen?

Please help.